# Add element inside of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new at web development and trying to figure out how to add an element inside of element.

[image]

```css
.blackBox {
  background: #000;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text {
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
}

.redBox {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBox">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... </div>
  <div class="redBox" />
</div>
```

Comment: A quick note `<div />` is not valid html : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you'll need for this. First, you'll want to give your `.redBox` a `position` of `absolute`, along with giving the parent `.blackBox` a `position` of `relative`. After this, give your red box a `top` of `0` so that the elements overlap.

You'll also need to give the red box a `width` and `height`. I've gone with `100%` for the `height`, and `150%` for the `width`. This is to make the red box bigger than the container, so that it will go right to the edges. A negative `margin-left` is used to offset this.

From here it's simply a matter of giving the red box negative rotation with `transform: rotate(-5deg)`. Finally, you'll want to give your `.blackBox` an `overflow: hidden` to hide the parts where the red box goes outside the bounds of its container.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.blackBox {
  background: #000;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.redBox {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBox">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... </div>
  <div class="redBox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great detail of the `css` but just missing the `border-radius` on `.blackBox`

Comment: I've added that in now :)

Comment: Much better :) +1 for this one!

Comment: thx you, this was helpful. Also the .text would need a position. I added that in :)

Answer (score 2):

What about **one element** and some gradient as background:

```css
.blackBox {
  padding:50px;
  width:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-top:10px solid #000;
  border-bottom:10px solid #000;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 51%) 0 0/100% 40px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,#000 51%) 0 100%/100% 40px no-repeat,
  red;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBox">
  Lorem Ipsum Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to set the container [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to relative and absolute position the `text` and `redBox` elements. Then give each of them an appropriate [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) value so that the text overlays the red box.

You could then use [`skewY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skewY) transformation to achieve the skewed effect.

I've also used [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) to get the rounded border you have in the image.

e.g.

```css
.blackBox {
  background: black;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.redBox {
  position:absolute;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 110px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 45px;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBox">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... </div>
  <div class="redBox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.blackBox {
  background: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.text {
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.redBox {
  background: darkred;
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  left: -40px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBox">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... </div>
  <div class="redBox">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [Obsdidian Ages answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725027/4665), you can do this without the additional, meaningless, "redbox" element. Instead use a pseudo element like `:before`. I would also say you are better off giving `blackbox` a relative position, internal elements are then positioned relative to it.

To get the text displaying as white, give the `.text` element `position:absolute` and a `z-index` higher than out `:before` pseudo-element.

```css
.blackBox {
  background: #000;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:30px;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  position:absolute;
}

.blackBox:before {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  content:'';
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBox">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit... </div>
</div>
```